# Heroku Free Service

Tags: javascript, heroku, hour, dyno

So I am currently using Heroku's free service to run my Discord Bot.

I saw that it will sleep every 30 minutes if it isn't used. If the bot is used after 30 minutes, will the app wake up by itself or will I need to consistently wake it up.

Also, when the plan says I can **verify** with a credit card to get a total of 1000 free dyno hours, does that mean that I won't have to pay anything but only verify?

Thanks for all your help,
Traid

Comment: Be aware, this type of question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Please check: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746

Comment: The going to sleep only refers to web dynos. Since you aren't hosting a web service (like a web page) you aren't affected by it. Your dyno will still restart after 24 hours. You don't have to pay. Only verify.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wake up the bot after every 30 minutes, however there are many ways that you can around this. You can create a program that will "ping" the bot every 29 minutes so it never goes to sleep.

If your Heroku is verified, you will not be charged.